# jQuery caches AJAX request in IE even though cache: "false" is set

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, caching

I have the following code

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
  url: "/" + filename,
  dataType: "xml",
  cache: "false",
  success: function(xml)
{
    /* Parsing code here */
}});
```

In Chrome etc the requests are not cached, however they are in IE.  Am I constructing my request properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cache` should be a boolean, not a string:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
  url: "/" + filename,
  dataType: "xml",
  cache: false,
  success: function(xml){
    /* Parsing code here */
  }  
});
```

Comment: +1 a string `"false"` will be interpreted as `true` if not compared using `===`.

Comment: @Pekka - that's true, but in this specific case, [jQuery DOES compare with ===](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L261), however it only attempts to avoid cache if `s.cache === false` (but of course, "false" === false => false)

Comment: @James: Good job you choose programming over comedy as a career path. :P

Comment: It was the bool thing, changing from `"false"` to `false` worked. ta

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the mimetype of the xml file you are returning?
http://www.nerdydork.com/ie-json-caching-bug.html

One commenter on my blog suggested adding a time string to the json request:

> I’m not going to trust in setting the
>   cache to off in .ajaxSetup….
>
> So just add a time string at the end
>   of each json request, e.g.
>
> $.getJSON( ‘/url/’, { data: 123, t:
>   (new Date()).getTime() },
>   function(data) { //do whatever } );

Comment: `I’m not going to trust in setting the cache to off in .ajaxSetup…` - Why??? It does _exactly_ the same thing!