# jQuery's ajax not working on IE6 :(

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm developing a website using asp.net mvc and I have this image that fire an Ajax event when clicked. It works just fine on FF and IE 7 & 8, but on IE 6 it doesn't even call the method on the controller (I did put a breakpoint there and ran it on debug mode to check). I'm on it for a few days now and can't find a solution. Here's my code:

```
    <img src="/Content/Images/img.png" onclick="HideAll(); GetMyVonparDiv(this); 
         $.ajax({ url: '/<%= Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["language"] %>/myvonpar/AddContent/?idContent=<%= ViewData.Model.id_content.ToString() %>&static=<%= ViewData.Model.is_static %>',
         type: 'GET',
         success: function (msg) { if (msg == 'True') { $(parentDiv).prev('.ok').show(); } else { $(parentDiv).show(); } },
         error: function (msg) {  }
    });" />
```

The url for the method is generated correctly (`/pt/myvonpar/AddContent/?idContent=258&static=False`) and, as i said before, it works on every other browser but IE6 :(

---

**Edit:** The same JS code formatted for better readability:

```
HideAll();
GetMyVonparDiv(this); 

$.ajax({
    url: '/<%= Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["language"] %>/myvonpar/AddContent/?idContent=<%= ViewData.Model.id_content.ToString() %>&static=<%= ViewData.Model.is_static %>',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (msg) { 
        if (msg == 'True') { 
            $(parentDiv).prev('.ok').show();
        } else { 
            $(parentDiv).show();
        }
    },
    error: function (msg) {  }
});
```

Comment: There are just times when you need to stop supporting a decade old browser.

Comment: I've never seen so much code inside the onclick attribute...

Comment: @Chris IE6 is still well in the two digits (>10%). Maybe in a year ...

Comment: It will be much easier for you to debug if you put onclick handler into a separate method and not inline into html. Just saying :)

Comment: Interesting. Techcrunch has it below 5% usage. http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/01/statcounter-browser-share/

Comment: @Chris Wikipedia is at 7.6%. Netapplications is at 13.72%. Like I said, maybe in a year... you know, 2012, the end of IE6 :)

Comment: Cause and effect. If developers STOP SUPPORTING IE6, then users will STOP USING IE6.

Comment: @Andrey +1 for removing it from the OnClick attribute and moving it to a method.

Comment: @rock Try to tell that to the devs at Facebook. They'll keep supporting IE6 for years, because even a 0.1% page view drop is a considerable financial loss for them.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - unfortunately the opposite is also true - developers have to support IE6 because a significant number of users are still using it.

Comment: @Vidas http://gs.statcounter.com/ says IE6 is below 5% for Europe, North America, and Oceania, and just above 6% globally (mainly because it has more than 50% in China). Facebook is already dropping support for it, for the record.

Comment: Look, not making is IE6 compatible is not an option, unfortunately the client demands it, and signed a contract stating that the website HAS to work properly on IE6, and my boss accepted it, so I don't have much of a voice on this matter. Anyway, I found what's causing the problem, is some error that DD_belatedPNG is causing. When I remove it, the ajax works, but the pngs no. I tried a couple other plugins and they cause the same problem. And I can't find anything about this error. So I'm kinda stuck on this one :(

Comment: PNG support in IE6 pretty much sucks too. Look into this http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/ or this http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar problem and it turned out that IE was caching the get query.  see [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782283/jquery-caches-ajax-request-in-ie-even-though-cache-false-is-set)

Comment: +1, this bit me quite hard as well. Even if caching isn't the issue, I've gotten into the habit of setting cache: false and ifModified: true.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding traditional:true