# AJAX reload button sometimes prepends the same message multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX function to check for new messages and then prepend the new messages to the `#message`. But, my problem is that this function triggers every 20 seconds, but whenever you click the Refresh button that instantly triggers the function, it messes up. Here is my functions for the AJAX:

```
function ajaxMail() {
    var message_id = $('.line:first').attr('id');
    jQuery.ajax({ //new mail
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: "/employee/message/check_mail.php",
        data: {
            latest_id: message_id,
            t: Math.random()
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            $('#messages_inner').prepend(data);
        }
    });
}

function updateTitles() {
    //if(titleChange !== false) {
    $.get('update.php?type=title', function(data) {
        document.title = data;
    });
    //}
    $.get('update.php?type=header', function(data) {
        $('#heading').html(data);
    });
    $.get('update.php?type=total', function(data) {
        $('#total').html('Total messages: ' + data);
    });
    setTimeout("updateTitles();ajaxMail();", 20000);
}
updateTitles();
```

And for the Refresh button this is what I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#refresh').click(function() {
        ajaxMail();
        updateTitles();
    });
});
```

Sometimes, the same exact message gets prepended to the message div because of the button or something. (but when I refresh of course there aren't 2 of the same message anymore) This is one time when the same message was prepended multiple times:

[image]

First, I pressed the Refresh button and it prepended the new message. But then about 5 seconds later the funciton triggered again and for some reason prepended the same message again. Also as you can see the Inbox count says 2 because really there is only 2 ("Test" and "Test12345"), but for some reason the "Test12345" got prepended 2 times.

Does anyone know why it is doing this? I can also provide the code for `check_mail.php` if you  need to see it.

Comment: Thanks @3nigma for putting the second code in a code box. I had it before but something messed it up.

Comment: just a hunch try setting `cache:false` in your ajaxMail ajax req, though Math.Random() is already doing it

Comment: @3nigma So just add `cache:false` in the $.ajax? But if Math.Random() is already doing it what will `cache:false` do?

Comment: Math.random generates a random number which breaks the cache but i was thinking what if the same random number is generated cache:false does more or less the same thing but it adds the milliseconds ...are you handling the multiple request with the same message_id at the server?

Comment: Well, `message_id` is the newest message, because what my code above does is checks to see if new messages were sent and then it prepends the new line to the inbox div. It is kinda like Gmail a little as you can see. How do I use cache:false with my `$.ajax` code above?

Comment: see how cache false is used though the question is not related http://stackoverflow.com/q/2782283/413670

Comment: @3nigma Oh, thanks! I thought it was: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: Yeah, it seems fixed now. Actually I've been using the `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` since yesterday when I searched on Google how to use the cache:false and that seems to make it work. Thanks for your help. I'll probably clear the timeout as well as sacah has said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend trying `cache:false` too, I've had browsers caching an ajax request even through I was sending a random string along. 
Also, consider clearing the timeout before you set it again, as each time the refresh button is pressed it starts another timeout.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a value that can be used to cancel it.  `var timer = setTimeout('yourFunctions', 20000); clearTimeout(timer);`  Of course, if the refresh function will execute `clearTimeout`, `timer` will either have to be global or passed in.