# PHP Ajax requests are cached by Internet Explorer 9

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer-9

When I call:

```
$("#id").load("file.php");
```

Internet Explorer 9 uses a cached response of `file.php` instead of take the updated response.

At the moment the only solution I've found is to use:

```
$("#id").load("file.php?random=" + Math.random() );
```

But it doesn't looks a nice solution.
How could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem in IE8

Similar to what you posted in the question, we used to use the following

```
url = url +'?rnd=' + Math.random();
```

However after reading [jQuery caches AJAX request in IE even though cache: "false" is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782283/jquery-caches-ajax-request-in-ie-even-though-cache-false-is-set), I am planning to use `cache: false`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajaxSetup ({    
  cache: false
});
```

Should do the job.

Comment: This problem happens only on IE... Shouldn't this command affect all the browsers and so shouldn't I have the problem even on Chrome and Firefox without it?

Comment: Could be it depends on browser settings, IE could cache, and then you could set your ajax.